# Why doesn't parameters.getFlashMode() == Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF return true?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

I am trying to determine if flash is on or off so that with one button I can toggle it on and off. Here is my code :

```
Camera cam = getCameraInstance(); //A method that opens the cam
            Camera.Parameters parameters = cam.getParameters();
            System.out.println("Current flash mode " + parameters.getFlashMode());
            System.out.println("flash mode off equals to : " + Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            System.out.println(parameters.getFlashMode() == Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
```

The output for the first two syso's is `off`. Naturally I assumed that because they both return an `off` string putting the `==` operator between them would return `true` (thus allowing me to check if flash is on) but it returns `false`. Any idea why?

I am targeting for api 16 and testing on a Marshmallow device

Comment: Have you checked what is returned by `parameters.getFlashMode()`? My guess is that it returns `null`, that's because flash mode setting is not supported on your device.

Comment: The output for `System.out.println("Current flash mode " + parameters.getFlashMode());` is an `off` string. I assume were it null it would return a `null` string

Comment: In this case, it's becuase of == instead of equals()

Comment: Ohhh thats why! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html) you'll see that these parameters are `String`s, and you don't compare strings in Java with `==`. You do that with [`equals`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/4778343).